# FFMPEG "Unable to find a suitable output format for 'udp://<ip>:<port>'"

Tags: ffmpeg, udp

I am trying to figure out how to get FFMPEG to stream my desktop to UDP so that I can then see from VLC Media Player on a LAN connected device.

The command I'm trying to run is as follows:

`.\ffmpeg.exe -loglevel 56 -video_size 1920x1200 -f dshow -i video="screen-capture-recorder" "udp://192.168.1.10:5000"`

Which ends up erroring out, stating:

`Unable to find a suitable output format for 'udp://192.168.1.10:5000'`

`udp://192.168.1.10:5000 Invalid Argument`

Comment: Add `-f mpegts` before the output and start VLC listening before you start ffmpeg.

Comment: @Gyan Well, it seems that VLC sees the stream now, but it's not displaying it. https://pastebin.com/HBnwDt8y